# how do I catch a click outside some container using prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

```
    document.observe('click', function(e, el) {
        if (e.target != Element.descendantOf('calendar')) {
            $('calendar').fade();
        }
    });
```

I am trying to do something when a click is registered outside a certain container. In my code above, it's the $('calendar').

The above doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.observe('click', function(e, el) {
            if ( ! e.target.descendantOf('calendar')) {
                Effect.toggle('calendar', 'appear', {duration: 0.4});
            }
        });
```

I think this is working now. If anyone has something better. I'll be happy to hear them

Comment: this may raise an error on old IE : Object doesn't support property or method 'descendantOf'